# Max across Groups

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have the following data:

```
Date, Symbol, Close
2021-01-01, AAPL, 10
2021-01-02, AAPL, 12
2021-01-03, AAPL, 3
2021-01-01, MSFT, 12
2021-01-02, MSFT, 20
2021-01-03, MSFT, 12
2021-01-01, MSFT, 1
2021-01-02, MSFT, 2
2021-01-03, MSFT, 3
```

1. I'd like to find the max Close value per day for 'MSFT'
2. Transpose/transform it into a series in the existing dataframe as 'MSFT_MAX_CLOSE'

I tried the following but get NaN

```
df['MSFT_MAX_CLOSE'] = df.loc[df['Symbol']=='MSFT'].groupby(['Date'])['Close'].transform(max)
```

Expected output

```
Date, Symbol, Close, MSFT_MAX_CLOSE
2021-01-01, AAPL, 10, 12
2021-01-02, AAPL, 12, 20
2021-01-03, AAPL, 3, 12
2021-01-01, MSFT, 12, 12
2021-01-02, MSFT, 20, 20
2021-01-03, MSFT, 12, 12
2021-01-01, MSFT, 1, 12
2021-01-02, MSFT, 2, 20
2021-01-03, MSFT, 3, 12
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to propagate the values to other groups, [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) won't work. You can aggregate with [`groupby.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.max.html), then [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the values per date:

```
msft_max = (df.loc[df['Symbol'].eq('MSFT')]
              .groupby('Date')['Close'].max()
           )

df['MSFT_MAX_CLOSE'] = df['Date'].map(msft_max)
```

Output:

```
         Date Symbol  Close  MSFT_MAX_CLOSE
0  2021-01-01   AAPL     10              12
1  2021-01-02   AAPL     12              20
2  2021-01-03   AAPL      3              12
3  2021-01-01   MSFT     12              12
4  2021-01-02   MSFT     20              20
5  2021-01-03   MSFT     12              12
6  2021-01-01   MSFT      1              12
7  2021-01-02   MSFT      2              20
8  2021-01-03   MSFT      3              12
```

##### generalization to all Symbols

If you want to do this for all symbols, then better change the approach. First aggregate on both Date/Symbol, then [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
out = df.merge(df.groupby(['Date', 'Symbol'])['Close'].max()
                 .unstack().add_suffix('_MAX_CLOSE'),
               left_on='Date', right_index=True, how='left'
               )
```

Output:

```
         Date Symbol  Close  AAPL_MAX_CLOSE  MSFT_MAX_CLOSE
0  2021-01-01   AAPL     10              10              12
1  2021-01-02   AAPL     12              12              20
2  2021-01-03   AAPL      3               3              12
3  2021-01-01   MSFT     12              10              12
4  2021-01-02   MSFT     20              12              20
5  2021-01-03   MSFT     12               3              12
6  2021-01-01   MSFT      1              10              12
7  2021-01-02   MSFT      2              12              20
8  2021-01-03   MSFT      3               3              12
```